# How many ways are there to make a $3$ digit number out of - $1,2,3,4,5,5$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am confused. What is the problem if I solve by this way

$\frac{(6 \cdot  5 \cdot 4)}{2!}$

Because two digits are repeated, and using permutations method I get the answer to be $60$ ways

But in solution it also chooses to take $5$, $5$ _ as a way, arranging them.

But does the above method of diving by the repetition does not already take this into account?

Comment: Distinguish the two $5$s (as $5$ and $V$). Among the $6\times5\times 4$ permutations, it's correct to deduplicate some pairs: e.g. $125$ and $12V$; $54V$ and $V45$; etc. But not all permutations are in pairs to be deduplicated, for example $123$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the question why "the above method of dividing by the repetition does not already take this into account":

Distinguish the two $5$s (as $5$ and $V$). Among the $6\times5\times 4$ permutations,

- it's correct to deduplicate some pairs: e.g. $\{125,12V\}$, $\{54V, V45\}$, etc.
- But not all permutations are in pairs to be deduplicated, e.g. $123$.

In fact, to permute just $1,2,3,4$ and only one $5$ to form a $3$-digit number already gives $5\times4\times3 = 60$ ways.